# Canvas class in awt

Tags: java, canvas, applet, awt

Develop an program that contains three check boxes and 30 x 30 pixel canvas.The three checkboxes should be labeled “Red”, “Green”,”Blue”. The selection of the check boxes determine the color of the canvas. For example, if the user selects both “Red” and “Blue”, the canvas should be purple.

Comment: show what you have tried so far??

Comment: i tried following code it is right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

import java.awt.*;

import java.applet.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

//

public class canvasdemo extends Applet implements ItemListener
{

```
CanvasEx cx;
Checkbox c1,c2,c3;
int rc=0,gc=0,bc=0;
Color cl;

public canvasdemo()
{
    cx = new CanvasEx(); 
    cx.setSize(30,30);
    add(cx, "North");
    setSize(300, 200); 
    setVisible(true);
}

public void init()
{
    setLayout(null);

    c1=new Checkbox("red");
    c2=new Checkbox("green");
    c3=new Checkbox("blue");

    c1.setBounds(50,200,50,20);
    c2.setBounds(120,200,50,20);
    c3.setBounds(190,200,50,20);

    add(c1);
    add(c2);
    add(c3);

    c1.addItemListener(this);
    c2.addItemListener(this);
    c3.addItemListener(this);
}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent  e)
{
    if(c1.getState()==true)
    {
        rc=255;
    }
    else
    {
        rc=0;
    }
    if(c2.getState()==true)
    {
        bc=255;
    }
    else
    {
        bc=0;
    }
    if(c3.getState()==true)
    {
        gc=255;
    }
    else
    {
        gc=0;
    }
    cl = new Color(rc,gc,bc);
    cx.setBackground(cl);
}
```

}

class CanvasEx extends Canvas

{

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    new canvasdemo();

}
```

}

Comment: I can't tell, is this supposed to be an answer, or the code you've tried so far?

Comment: i tryed it and its working but i am confused that it is right or wrong